# Transfer folder using pscp (Putty) from Windows to Linux

Tags: pscp

Using puttys `pscp -r folder\to\copy\* user@server:/path/to/copy/folder/to` it only copies the content of `path\to\copy\folder\*` and does not include the "main" folder which the subfiles and subdirectories are in.

What I need is that the folder itself is also copied such that I get a folder with the same name as the one I copied with the content inside.

I know I just can create a parent-folder for the one I want to copy and parse that as the `path\to\copy\folder\*` but that is not the case

Answer (score 8):

Just use `pscp -r folder\to\copy user@server:/path/to/copy/folder/to`.

Note that the backslash (`\`) after the original folder's name **needs to be omitted**. If you add a backslash, the content of the folder is copied, rather than the folder itself.

Comment: Note that the backslash after the original folder's name *needs to be omitted*. If you add a backslash, the content of the folder is copied, rather than the folder itself.

Comment: @Fato39 I read your comment 2 minutes too late